# Program type already present error

Tags: java, android, gradle

Although many similar questions exist, I checked the answers to all and none of them worked for me!

Here is the error I'm facing while compiling the code:

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 27
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.narsun.grocery"
       minSdkVersion 21
       targetSdkVersion 27
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       multiDexEnabled true
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   packagingOptions {

       exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
       exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
       exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
       exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

   }
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

   })
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

   implementation 'com.github.sd6352051.niftydialogeffects:niftydialogeffects:1.0.0@aar'
   implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
   implementation 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'
   implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
   implementation 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
   implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
   implementation 'com.github.myinnos:AwesomeImagePicker:1.0.2'
   implementation 'com.github.ratty3697:android-smart-animation-library:1.6'
   implementation 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'
   implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.6.1'
   implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.10'
   implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

You can tell me if there is anything else to add to understand what I'm doing or where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the packages versions are not compatible. Try downgrading `com.android.support` packages, namely `appcompat`

so - `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'`

Comment: Thanks, but the thing helped me, I just mentioned in my own answer.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone comes here with a similar issue. In my case it was because I had included an appcompat JAR file in the libs folder as well as having implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0' in my gradle file.

When I removed the JAR file, that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

I want to share how you can understand the error message.

First method, check your `dependencies` in `build.gradle`:

[image]

In this case, if I tried to remove that `implementation`, the error gone.

Second method, Check `libs` folder of your app which included .jar files:

[image]

In this case, if I tried to move that .jar to somewhere else, the error gone.

Comment: Not a soultion to my problem. But procedure to track down the issue helped me, so upvoting !!

Answer (score 1):

For the info for other who will face the same error, I was able to solve my problem by removing the following library from my gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
```

This was the library creating issues for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm including a custom `aar` in my `app/libs` folder, and I **correctly** added the `flatLib` object to the root `build.gradle`, but **incorrectly** added the `'*.aar'` to the `fileTree` implementation in the `app/build.gradle`:

---

**build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }

    }
}
```

---

**app/build.gradle**

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'])
                                                 ^^^
                                                 BAD
```